# spring-boot-admin, Version and Info not shown

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

One of our applications is configured with a custom context-path. In order to configure our Eureka Client, we added the following properties:

```
server.context-path=/ourApp
eureka.instance.statusPageUrlPath=${server.context-path}/info
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrlPath=${server.context-path}/health
```

Despite these properties, information for this application is not correctly found:

[image]

Also, when looking at the details for this application, the metrics are not found.

For application without any particular application context (using root -> "/"), it's working fine!

Any idea which other eureka.* properties might be missing?

Comment: Which version of spring boot are you using? 2.2.0 moved actuator paths under /actuator

Comment: We're using 1.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, following property is the one I was looking for:

`eureka.instance.metadata-map.management.context-path=${server.context-path}`